# Firestore updateDoc by id

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want update informations getting doc by id but I receive erros my code.

Idk how solve this sorry about my english. I just want to update the information I think is a basic error, but I can't solve it sorry

I receive Expected type 'Ta', but it was: a custom Aa object

```
const updateFields = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()

updateDoc(TopStoryAnswersCollectionRef, {
  response_B6: responseB6,
  response_B9: responseB9,
  response_B12: responseB12,
  response_B15: responseB15,
  response_B18: responseB18,
  response_B21: responseB21,
  response_B24: responseB24,
  response_B27: responseB27,
  response_B28: responseB28,
  response_B29: responseB29,
  response_B32: responseB32,
  response_B33: responseB33,
  response_B34: responseB34,
  response_B35: responseB35,
  response_B38: responseB38,
  user_uid: currentUser.uid,
}).then(() => {
  alert('Updated')
})
setFormSubmitted(true)
```

}

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible code? I suspect that the error comes from the `TopStoryAnswersCollectionRef` variable.

Comment: idk how repproducible code sorry, but I define like it: const TopStoryAnswersCollectionRef = collection(db, 'topStoryAnswers')

Comment: Well, that's the issue. the reference should be a document reference not a collection reference. It should be like this: `const TopStoryAnswersCollectionRef = doc(db, "collection-name", "document-id");`

Comment: If you could post the full code that you have, I would gladly point out and correct the issue for you. I'm also not sure how you are getting the document ID and how you are passing it on the snippet above. I'll post my comment above as an answer for now and if you have clarifications, feel free to comment on my answer.

Comment: Have you checked my posted answer? Let me know if you have some questions or clarifications. Also, See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A&text=To%20mark%20an%20answer%20as,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `TopStoryAnswersCollectionRef` should be a reference to a document when using `updateDoc` not a reference to a collection. See sample code below:

```
const updateFields = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()

const TopStoryAnswersCollectionRef = doc(db, "collection-name", "document-id");

updateDoc(TopStoryAnswersCollectionRef, {
  response_B6: responseB6,
  response_B9: responseB9,
  response_B12: responseB12,
  response_B15: responseB15,
  response_B18: responseB18,
  response_B21: responseB21,
  response_B24: responseB24,
  response_B27: responseB27,
  response_B28: responseB28,
  response_B29: responseB29,
  response_B32: responseB32,
  response_B33: responseB33,
  response_B34: responseB34,
  response_B35: responseB35,
  response_B38: responseB38,
  user_uid: currentUser.uid,
}).then(() => {
  alert('Updated')
})
setFormSubmitted(true)
```

You could also incorporate a query using `where()` if you still don't have the document reference to update to.

---

For more information, you may checkout this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data).